# Why is it possible to access a constructor parameter after it becomes out of scope?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Why is it okay to call the **SomeMethod()** method in my example below?

I would think that the constructor parameter **loggerFactory** would no longer be available when the **Logger** property tries to access it.

I'm using a function when I set the **lazyLogger** field, but I thought it would throw an exception of sorts when I call the **Logger** property.

But everything works just fine.
This might just be my misunderstanding of how the CLR/C# works.

I would appreciate an explanation for why it works this way.

```
public class TestClass
{
  private readonly Lazy<ILogger> lazyLogger;

  private ILogger Logger => this.lazyLogger.Value;

  public TestClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    this.lazyLogger = new Lazy<ILogger>(() = > loggerFactory.GetLogger("TestLogger"));
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    this.Logger.Info("Test Log Message"); //Why is it okay to call this method?  The constructor parameter shouldn't be available anymore, right?
  } 
}

public interface ILoggerFactory
{
  ILogger GetLogger(string name);
}

public interface ILogger
{
  void Info(string message);
}

public class TestLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
  public ILogger GetLogger(string name)
  {
      return new TestLogger(name);
  }
}

public class TestLogger : ILogger
{
  public void Info(string message)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're closing over `loggerFactory` in the delegate passed to the `Lazy<ILogger>` constructor.

Comment: Hey, if I put my valuables in a box then give that box to someone, how did he get my valuables? I never gave him them, I only gave him a box!

Comment: @Lee, when you say that I'm **closing over**, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're accessing this parameter inside the lambda

```
() = > loggerFactory.GetLogger("TestLogger");
```

the compiler creates some extra code to capture that variable. It looks something like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    /* your fields here */

    // created by compiler
    private ILoggerFactory anonymousField; 
    private ILogger AnonymousMethod()
    {
         return anonymousField.GetLogger("TestLogger");
    }

    public TestClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // save field
        this.anonymousField = loggerFactory;
        // use instance method instead with captures anonymousField
        this.lazyLogger = new Lazy<ILogger>(AnonymousMethod); 
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments, actually a whole new class gets generated that declares that anonymous method and takes all necessary variables as fields. But that's the basic idea.

Comment: The **closing over** aspect is new to me.  Might be my fault for not having this knowledge.

Comment: Actually the compiler creates a new delegate class for the lambda containing a field for the captured variable.

Comment: @IssaFram Sorry, my english sometimes lacks the correct wording for this compiler magic. Though it's enough for a normal conversation, I never understand why it's called/what the exact meaning of "closure"/"capture" etc.. is in this context.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not sure about this, a while ago I checked the decompiled IL and I think I remember that as long as possible it keeps the values in the same class. Not sure if this is an implementation detail.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/742474/880990 and for more in-depth information: [The Beauty of Closures C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx). Both by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Closure is a [term of art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) from computer sceince.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes re-checked, you are right. Unfortunatly I'm running out of time now, will update the answer tomorrow if noone finds a good dup til then. And I guess I described the basic idea.